# Hash sum of partitions that haven't been mounted changes every time after a live usb run

Tags: boot, security

I have a Live USB with puppy linux on it.

Here's menu entry in Grub2 for Puppy:

```
menuentry "Puppy Linux 6.0.5 tahrpup" {
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0641378e-ea07-4d6a-b238-4b35fd7a37b1
        linux /tahr/vmlinuz
        initrd /tahr/initrd.gz
        }
```

After a launch I do absolutely nothing, but run md5sum on /dev/sdaX to get checksums of partitions on the computer's hard drive, then shutdown.
Then I launch Puppy again run md5sum and get different numbers for boot, and root partitions of the system on the hard drive, but same for grub partition.
As far as I know, puppy doesn't mount them automatically.
Question: what am I missing in understanding of linux boot? Is there some kernel flag to prevent such behavior?

Comment: Are you mounting them read only?  The "last accessed" time is stored in file inodes; I've never heard of running md5sum directly on a partition....

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected (MD5sum being different on bootup when using Puppy on a usb drive).
assuming your using a multisession flag.
This [url](http://barryk.org/puppylinux/development/howpuppyworks.html) may help understand if this is in fact to be expected based on the way you are using Puppy linux.